# How to loop through arrays in hash table - passing parameters based on values read from a CSV file

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

Curious about how to loop through a hash table where each value is an array. Example:

```
 $test = @{
 a = "a","1";
 b = "b","2";
 c = "c","3";
 }
```

Then I would like to do something like:

```
foreach ($T in $test) {
write-output $T
}
```

Expected result would be something like:

```
name value
a    a
b    b
c    c
a    1
b    2
c    3
```

That's not what currently happens and my use case is to basically pass a hash of parameters to a function in a loop. My approach might be all wrong, but figured I would ask and see if anyone's tried to do this?

Edit**
A bit more clarification. What I'm basically trying to do is pass a lot of array values into a function and loop through those in the hash table prior to passing to a nested function. Example:

First something like:

```
$parameters = import-csv .\NewComputers.csv
```

Then something like

```
 $parameters | New-LabVM
```

Lab VM Code below:

```
function New-LabVM 
{

[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    # Param1 help description
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
               Position=0,
               ValueFromPipeline=$true,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias("p1")] 
    [string[]]$ServerName,

    # Param2 help description
    [Parameter(Position = 1)]
    [int[]]$RAM = 2GB,

    # Param3 help description
    [Parameter(Position=2)]
    [int[]]$ServerHardDriveSize = 40gb,

    # Parameter help description
    [Parameter(Position=3)]
    [int[]]$VMRootPath = "D:\VirtualMachines",
    [Parameter(Position=4)]
    [int[]]$NetworkSwitch = "VM Switch 1",
    [Parameter(Position=4)]
    [int[]]$ISO = "D:\ISO\Win2k12.ISO"
  )

 process 
 {
 New-Item -Path $VMRootPath\$ServerName -ItemType Directory
 $Arguments = @{
 Name = $ServerName;
 MemoryStartupBytes = $RAM;
 NewVHDPath = "$VMRootPath\$ServerName\$ServerName.vhdx";
 NewVHDSizeBytes = $ServerHardDriveSize
 SwitchName = $NetworkSwitch;}

foreach ($Argument in $Arguments){
    # Create Virtual Machines
New-VM @Arguments

# Configure Virtual Machines
Set-VMDvdDrive -VMName $ServerName -Path $ISO
Start-VM $ServerName
}
# Create Virtual Machines
New-VM @Arguments
 }
}
```

Comment: Does the result have to be exactly like that? I can imagine an easy way to get an "a-a-b-b-c-c" (under name) pattern without too much change. If you want exactly what you have, perhaps creating an object will suit your needs. Let me know and I'll put up some solution code.

Comment: It doesn't, I'm basically trying to pass multiple values to a function in the pipeline without having to loop through arrays. Not sure how to post code in the comments here. I'll see if i can update the original question.

Comment: just tested your code, it actually works a lot better than I had imagined. Give me a minute, I'll figure something out for you.

Comment: Just updated the question with some more code to see if that helps. I think the value should have the same name as the key since it's an expected parameter for the function i'm passing to in the pipeline. I think I can fix this by setting up my hash table within the loop, just looking for another way to loop through the nested arrays in the hash table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [parameter splatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).

The most robust way to do that is via *hashtables*, so you must convert the custom-object instances output by `Import-Csv` to hashtables:

```
Import-Csv .\NewComputers.csv | ForEach-Object {
   # Convert the custom object at hand to a hashtable.
   $htParams = @{}
   $_.psobject.properties | ForEach-Object { $htParams[$_.Name] = $_.Value }

   # Pass the hashtable via splatting (@) to the target function.
   New-LabVM @htParams
}
```

Note that since parameter binding via splatting is *key*-based (the hashtable keys are matched against the parameter names), it is fine to use a *regular* hashtable with its unpredictable key ordering (*no* need for an *ordered* hashtable (`[ordered] @{ ... }`) in this case).

Comment: @Luisrorta: No worries at all - thanks for being willing to learn how things work around here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for($i=0;$i -lt $test.Count; $i++)
    {$test.keys | %{write-host $test.$_[$i]}}
```

Weirdly, it outputs everything in the wrong order (because $test.keys outputs it backwards).

**EDIT:** Here's your solution.

Using the `[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]` type, you guarantee that the output will come out the same order as you entered it.

```
$test = [ordered] @{
 a = "a","1";
 b = "b","2";
 c = "c","3";
 }
```

After running the same solution code as before, you get exactly the output you wanted.

Comment: Well, that does actually answer the original question looking back on what I was asking. However, I need the key values to match up the parameters in the proceeding function.  That being said, this bit of code gets me a lot closer! I think I can mess with this to make it work to do what I want to do. Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: @Luisrorta I figured that the ordered dictionary would solve your problem. Take another look at my solution.

Comment: "because $test.keys outputs it backwards" is misleading: the key ordering of a regular hashtable is an _implementation detail_; in other words: no particular order is guaranteed; by contrast, `[ordered] @{ ... }` indeed guarantees the ordering of keys in definition order.

Comment: @mklement0 that's true, but the output I was describing was also ordered backwards.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You're enumerating `$test.keys` in your first snippet, and that will give you no predictable order. As an aside: [please don't use `Write-Host`](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).

Comment: @mklement0 The output I got from trying this myself was ordered backwards, due how it was previously defined and manipulated. I realise that it was luck, so after considering switching it's order using `[$test.count - $i]` as the array reference, I realised that this would not work and switched to an ordered dictionary. As for `write-host`, you are right, thanks for the blog post. I usually keep `Write-Host` in my answer if the person puts it in their question, but here I realise I misread as the question contains `Write-Output`.

Comment: So the ordering _happened to be_ backwards, and now that you know that that was _happenstance_ and _why_, there is no need to keep the sentence "Weirdly, ..." in your answer. As for `Write-Host`: glad to hear you found the blog post useful. My recommendation is _not_ to keep `Write-Host` in your answer even if present in the question; it is much more helpful to point out that `Write-Host` is almost always the wrong tool to use. Speaking of: while use of  `Write-Output` is not incorrect, it is rarely ever needed (just rely on the default output behavior).

Comment: @mklement0 Feel free to edit my answer if you want to correct little things like that.